# Build GUI for a CLI application as a side project

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, command-line-interface, electron

I rencently developed a Java CLI application, it works fine, but i would like to add a GUI as a side project.

#### What i have

- A standalone Java CLI application
- No web framework
- No DI

#### What i want

- An [electron](https://electron.atom.io/) GUI
- The GUI must be standalone and not included in the main project
- GUI will have graphs, stats and basic commands like: start stop update and so on
- The GUI's state should be in realtime (i means, i would like the GUI to be notified by the Java app if something occurs, instead of spamming the Java app with the GUI)
- Since the GUI should be a side project, someway or another, i need to be able to enable/disable the RPC-like (in case someone would like to use CLI only)

#### My problem

I can't figure out how to communicate between the CLI application and the GUI. I think something like RPC will kind of suit my need, but's i'm not quite familiar to this kind of technologies.

This is basically my question, what would be the most suitable technologie for this project.

Comment: Where is state maintained? Can you introduce a data layer in between the GUI and CLI?

Comment: Well... there is no way to introduce a data layer. There should be no global "state", i must be able to run only the CLI application if i want to. Not everyone will need GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably an almost infinite number of ways to do this, but the first thing that I thought of is WebSockets. Presumably you would start your java CLI app first, which could start a WebSocket server. Then start the Electron app, and have it connect to the CLI.

As far as libraries and frameworks, this is explicitly **not** the place to ask/answer that, and doing so will likely get your question down-voted and closed.

Comment: Is this possible to easily enable/disable websocket based on a CLI argument? Sorry if my question is out of context, in which stackexchange website is it more suitable?

Comment: Sure - why not? You're writing the code - you can do whatever you want..

Comment: Well x) sounds true. i think i'll go with it. Thanks